# call php function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The user needs to enter the 4 input fields in order to get the result which is expense. The result will be using FV formula thus I searched online and found out the how FV formula can be used in PHP. Now i want to call the function of the FV formula using the jQuery as i want when the user entered all fields the results will auto come out in the id rExpenses but it doesn't work. It displays a blank page when I go the localhost. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Edit: I deleted the php part and change the code to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input').keyup(function(){
var $rincome = parseInt($('#textfield1').val());
var $rate = parseInt($('#textfield2').val());
var $age = parseInt($('#textfield3').val());
var $rage = parseInt($('#textfield4').val());
var rExpenses = FV($rate/100,$rage - $age ,0,$rincome,0);
$('#rExpenses').html((rExpenses).toFixed(2));
});
});
</script>
<b>Monthly retirement income (SGD):</b>
<input type="number" id="textfield1" value="<?php echo $_POST['rincome'];?>"         name="rincome" min = "0"  />
</p>

<p>
<b>Inflation rate (%):
<input type="number" id="textfield2" value="<?php echo $_POST['rate'];?>"     name="rate" min = "0" step = "0.1"/> 
</p>

<p>
<b>Current age:
<input type="number" id="textfield3" value="<?php echo $_POST['age'];?>"             name="age" min = "0" max = "70"/>
</p>

<p>
<b>Retirement age:
<input type="number" id="textfield4" value="<?php echo $_POST['rage'];?>"     name="rage" min = "0"/>
</p>

<p>
<b>The monthly expenses when you retire(inflation adjusted):<span id =     "rExpenses">$0.00</span>
</p>

<script>
function FV(rate, nper, pmt, pv, type) {
var pow = Math.pow(1 + rate, nper),
 fv;
if (rate) {
fv = (pmt*(1+rate*type)*(1-pow)/rate)-pv*pow;
} else {
fv = -1 * (pv + pmt * nper);
}
return fv.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Put single quote around php variable `var rExpenses = '<?php echo fv($rate/100,$rage - $age ,0,$rincome);?>';`. Try this.

Comment: If you really must use PHP why not use AJAX?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali sorry it still doesn't work

Comment: @Script47 i am really new to this, i have no idea how the AJAX works thus i didn't use that. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a PHP function from within JQuery because JQuery is running in the browser, and PHP is running on the server. You could do it as a remote sort of thing using an AJAX call, but that would be silly. Why not just translate the PHP function into Javascript, and have it on the page?

Looking at the page, I can see what you've done, and it looks like you're wanting to have the server do the calculation. If you want to do that, you'll probably have to create a form and post your values to the server, or, as I said above, do something with AJAX.

If it were me, I'd get rid of the PHP stuff, and have something like this instead (and yes, you can use $ signs in variable names in Javascript, but I'd recommend against this if you're going to mix PHP up with it):

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var $rincome = parseInt($('#textfield1').val());
    var $rate = parseInt($('#textfield2').val());
    var $age = parseInt($('#textfield3').val());
    var $rage = parseInt($('#textfield4').val());
    var rExpenses = fv($rate/100,$rage - $age ,0,$rincome);
    $('#rExpenses').html((rExpenses).toFixed(2));
});
```

then change your <?php and ?> tags at the end of the page into <script> and </script> tags. It won't work exactly, but you should be able to debug it easily enough in your browser tools.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer, I tried the code but it doesn't work. The rExpenses just did't change the number.

Comment: Assuming that what you have in the question is your latest code, you haven't tried my code. You're missing a lot of "$" and parseInts. I'd encourage you to declare each of the variables and check the values in your browser tools.

Comment: Just looking at what you have there, you'll also need to get rid of the "=0" in the fv function's parameter list since that will be stopping any javascript code running on the page.

Comment: Sorry, actually i tried both your code and the code in other answer. Both codes did not work so I just used his code to show that I did change the code. I have changed the code, do you mind to help me check again? because i do not know why it doesn't work. Thank you so much.

Comment: Remove the `echo $rincome` line, that's not Javascript ... it's PHP. Put `$(document).ready(function() {` before  `$('input')`, and another `});` after your existing `});` so it looks like @anirudh's. Get rid of your `.toFixed(2)` so that it doesn't fail, then start debugging your formula. Use your browser tools (right-click the page in Chrome and choose "Inspect Element").

Comment: Thank you so much. I figured out how it works and you also taught me how to debug on the webpage. Really very glad that you helped me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing two concepts here. **PHP runs on server**, which means when you call that php function, the result is a html file without any of the php code. So you cannot directly call php function in jquery, which runs on the generated HTML file.

I think translating the php function to a javscript function, which can be directly called is the best option you have now.

**The translated javascript function is as easy as below:**

```
function fv(r,n,p,pv=0)
{
    var sum = pv;
    for (var i=0;i<n;i++ )
    { 
        sum += sum*r + p;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**Then your jquery script block becomes**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var rExpenses = fv(("#textfield2").val()/100, ("#textfield4").val() - ("#textfield3").val(), 0, ("#textfield1").val());
    $('#rExpenses').html((rExpenses).toFixed(2));
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i tried the code you replied. However, it still doesn't work as the output for rExpenses is always $0.00. I do not know where went wrong.

Comment: Thank you too. Thank you for converting the php function to javascript because i really do not know how to convert. Thank you